# How to delete all but the most recent X subfolders in a folder?

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I've seen some one liners using ls, but I'd like to avoid that.

I'm writing a script that copies code to my server in a timestamped folder. The 'current' version is always symlinked to a constant path. That way, I can roll back if anything goes wrong. Now, every deployment makes a new folder, but I'd like to keep only the 3 latest.

Here's my current version:

```
ls -tp | grep '/$' | grep -v 'current\|shared' | tail -n +4 | xargs -d '\n' rm -rf --
```

This is executed in the containing folder, excludes files, and the two folders 'current' and 'shared' that I want to keep (current actually being the aforementioned symlink), and deletes all but the 3 newest as sorted by `ls -t`.

Is there a way I can do this without `ls`, and only using bash and the gnu toolchain?

All folders meant for pruning are named following this format:

```
$timestamp.$branch.$sha1
```

Where SHA1 and branch are info from git about what exactly was deployed.

The server runs Ubuntu Xenial.

Edit: Provide some examples of what the folders look like

Here's a listing from the deployment folder, how it looks right now:

```
drwxr-x--- 13 app www-data 4096 Mar 29 00:10 1490738956.develop.b806/
drwxr-x--- 13 app www-data 4096 Mar 29 00:19 1490739485.develop.ae01/
drwxr-x--- 14 app www-data 4096 Mar 29 03:33 1490751118.develop.f5b0/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 app www-data   40 Mar 29 03:33 current -> /home/app/deploy/1490751118.develop.f5b0/
drwx------  5 app root     4096 Mar 10 04:12 shared/
```

Comment: Can you add a few sample names?

Comment: Find will return items newer than 'x' where x is a file. You create the file with the timestamp you need using touch.

Comment: From your explanation, it looks like you want to "delete all but the most recent **3 subfolders** in a folder". Is this correct? If so, you should edit the title accordingly, otherwise please add some further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to delete all but the most recent 3 subfolders in a folder?**

You can make use of `find`, `sort`, `awk`, `xargs` and finally `rm`:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -not -path "current" -not -path "shared" -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -nr | awk 'NR > 3 {print $2}' | xargs rm -rf
```

**Breakdown:**

`find` versatile tool to look for files and directories and possibly execute commands on them

`*` take into consideration elements in the current folder

`-maxdepth 0` don't look in subfolders

`-type d` look for directories

`-not -path "current"` exclude the directory named "current"

`-not -path "shared"` exclude the directory named "shared"

`-printf "%T@ %p\n"` print the results, appending the timestamp in front of the directory names. This could be omitted in your case, since the directories are already timestamped.

`| sort -nr` sort the list according to the timestamp, in reverse order

`| awk 'NR > 3 {print $2}'` print all but the first three results, omitting the timestamp that was added earlier. This is where you choose how many to keep, just substitute the number `3`

`| xargs rm -rf` delete those directories and all their contents

**Edit:** in your case, since the directories' names already start with a timestamp, there's no need to add the timestamp again for `sort -nr` to be effective. Note that the `awk` syntax needs to be edited accordingly.

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -not -path "current" -not -path "shared" | sort -nr | awk 'NR > 3 {print $0}' | xargs rm -rf
```

**Reference:** see [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/exclude-directory-from-find-command) [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29899/how-can-i-use-find-and-sort-the-results-by-mtime) useful/similar Q&A.

Comment: Nice solution, Not sure who ninja'd who....

Answer (score 0):

In it's most basic form

```
touch -t 201003160120 some_file
find . -maxdepth  0 -type d ! -newer some_file -name \*.develop.\* -delete
```

As taken from https://serverfault.com/questions/122824/linux-using-find-to-locate-files-older-than-date

`! -newer some_file` tells it to match anything not newer than 'some_file'

`-name \*.develop.\*` tells it to only match names matching this pattern ( *.develop.*)

`-delete` - I hope this requires no explaination, **be careful!** (Use -print when testing!)

`-type d` - only directories

`-maxdepth  0` - don't recurse into subfolders.

Comment: I've added an example listing to the question. Does that help providing a better answer?

Comment: I like your answer, but in my understanding the OP is asking how to keep the X most recent element, where X is a number. He later adds that X = 3.

Comment: He could always subsitute the 3rd file in, but yeah... that wasn't there before :P